# Should we close custom program requirements as Too Broad or Off Topic?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, questions, close-reasons

Not sure why but I feel like few questions makes no sense whatsoever as far as the Generalized Functionality is concerned. I'm a web developer and I've programmed certain Systems *(Tailor Made)* where users have their custom requirements.

Posting such questions here should be considered as off-topic or should be closed as *too broad*. The reason am saying this is because the systems pre programmed online won't match the functionality user requires. And that's where the companies earn because they add or remove extra features.

---

Consider am asking a question like

Is there any Job Portal/Software available where I've certain functionality like,

- Admin Panel
- List Jobs
- Upload Resumes etc

Now here, the issue is not each and every feature will match the users requirement, and thus users will ignore answering such questions. These types or portals are generally programmed as per user requirements, and thus should be considered as off-topic and should be closed.

---

Examples of Such Questions :

1. [Logging truck deliveries program?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/2936)
2. [Software to track donations and donors for a European non-profit?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3168/software-to-track-donations-and-donors-for-a-european-non-profit)
3. [Stack Exchange-like open-source platform where questions are suggestions and answers are input, never solutions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3132/stack-exchange-like-open-source-platform-where-questions-are-suggestions-and-ans)
4. [Need a forum with user integration](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3284/need-a-forum-with-user-integration)

---

It's just like using Presta Shop or Virtue Mart for an online shop, but hardly anyone uses the default, rest wants to customize somehow, so questions which are so functionality/requirement specifics will never be answered, and if they are, than the answers won't be that perfect.

And am sure this will create a real bad issue in the long run, think like we Closed the question as a duplicate just because the title matches, **BUT** user can complain that not all requirements match to the linked question, so we have to do nothing but reopen the question and thus the crap starts accumulating.

Questioning something like Q/A portal, Online Shop Portal can be taken into consideration rather than closing them as *too broad* as they have common things in nature, rest depends on user how to customize by himself or hiring some developer.

This way, we did answered A TYPE of portal/software which fulfills the requirements, rest needs to be handled by the user himself.

Answer (score 0):

I agree we must handle such questions somehow.

I recommend a custom close reason "Off-Topic">"Needs to be coded"

> Your question is about a program that needs to be tailor made for you. We favor questions that are about a general problem. Please try to reword your question to address a general problem. If you are capable of programming yourself please reword the question to ask for a library that tackles one of the given problems.

Until we have a custom close reason we should use that text (or something better worded) as comment for the close "off-topic">"custom".